# Why won't Pixel 7 accept voice recognition?

Tags: google-pixel, voice-recognition, google-assistant

I activated my Pixel 7 on September 21.  Voice recognition worked for two days, now hasn't worked since September 22. Phone calls work, people can hear me.  The Camera successfully captures sound when recording video.

However, voice recognition no longer works for apps where it is the primary purpose of the app.

- I open **Google Assistant**, the screen indicates it is listening for my input, but nothing changes or comes on screen when I speak to it
- When using GBoard, I click the mic icon to begin **speech to text**.  The phone dings, the mic flashes indicating it is ready for me to speak, but does not transcribe any text as I am speaking
- I hit record in **Recorder**, and it doesn't capture any audio when speaking to it
- **Now Playing** doesn't work, no songs have been captured since 9/22 despite being around plenty of music

Here's everything I've tried:

- Install all latest system updates
- Ensure all Google Assistant and voice permissions are enabled
- Restart phone in Safe Mode and out of Safe Mode
- Factory reset phone and log in with a different Google account

The phone has never been dropped or seen any liquids. Everything else functions as expected.

Does anyone have advice on how to correct this? (I would assume it's not a hardware issue, if phone calls and video audio capture work with no issue)

Comment: Do you see the green microphone notifier in the upper right corner in apps where recording doesn't work?

Comment: Your mic could still be faulty. I sometimes get issues, but I  suspect are due to apps competing for yhe microphone.

Comment: @Robert yes I do